# how to get the respective array key value if it meets the if condition in for loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have any array with keys and values , I want to get the value of the key ,if key is equal to certain string.

When I use this code I am getting the last key value of array. I have the flexibility to change the array structure also if we want.

```
$grouparray =[ "red" => "4" , "blue" =>"5" , "green" => "6"];

foreach($grouparray   as $x=>$x_value){
          if($x=blue){
              $group_id=$x_value;

          }

      }

print_r($group_id);
```

I want to expect `$group_id = 5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your `if` statement :

Replace `if ($x=blue) {` by `if ($x == "blue") {`

1. `Blue` is a string so you need some quote
2. `=` is to assign value, `==` or `===` are for comparaison.

But you shouldn't do a foreach loop to get your answer. If you just do `$group_id = $grouparray['blue'];` you will get what you want, not sure why you need a loop ?

Answer (score 0):

your are missing quotes on blue.

```
$grouparray =[ "red" => "4" , "blue" =>"5" , "green" => "6"];

    foreach($grouparray as $x=>$x_value){
              if($x=="blue"){
                  $group_id=$x_value;

              }

          }

    print_r($group_id);
```